# Google Chrome creates a debug.log file everywhere, is it infected?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, malware

In every folder where I open an HTML file with Google Chrome it recently started creating a *debug.txt* file. The result is that I have hundreds of *debug.txt* files on my harddrive in every template folder. This is unwanted.

Only while Google Chrome is still running, I am not allowed to delete *debug.txt* because it is in use. After I closed the browser I can delete it without problems.

When I open the HTML file with any other browser (FireFox, Edge and even Chrome Canary) no debug file is created.

Google Chrome has no third party plugins installed. Besides, plugins do not have access to the file system.

I suspected that Google Chrome was infected with Malware somehow. A fresh install did not solve the problem. A licensed version of *Malwarebytes Anti-Malware* does not find anything when I run a complete system scan.

Please help me understand the reason for this behavior and how to stop it. Thank you in advance.

The content of the file always looks approximately like this:

```
[0707/055229.280:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(426)] unexpected header
```

Comment: Are you sure it's debug.txt and not debug.log?

Comment: @Neil Oh! You are right, it is debug.log, where does it come from?

Comment: I found another page somewhere.   Can you see if your shortcut to start Chrome has --enable-log or you have an environment variable CHROME_LOG_FILE

Comment: @Neil I have neither. There is no environment variable and the shortcut does not have any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Chromium bug and it's back again. Chromium issue [1138853](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1138853) merged with [711159](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711159).

The last issue update says,

> This should be fixed in 88.0.4302.0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with Chrome, I have raised a [Bug - Issue 754045](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754045).